# solo me muestra el primer registro de mi consulta

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hola amigos tengo un problema con mi consulta, resulta que estoy haciendo una consulta con tablas relacionadas mi tabla: inscripción_proyectos la relaciono con mi tabla: inscripción_alumnos por medio del id de la tabla inscripción_proyectos y ese id lo guardo en la tabla inscripción_alumnos con el nombre idinscripcionproyecto eso es para saber cuántos alumnos pertenecen a ese proyecto ahora el único problema que tiene mi consulta es que si hay tres alumnos inscritos en 1 proyecto solo me muestra el primer alumno y no debería ser ya que si hay tres o más alumnos inscritos a ese proyecto deberían mostrarse los alumnos que se encuentren registrados al proyecto anexo mi consulta para saber que estoy haciendo mal.

```
    $id= $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT 
inscripcion_proyectos.id, 
inscripcion_proyectos.idcodificacion_proyectos,
inscripcion_proyectos.titulo_proyecto,
inscripcion_proyectos.iddepartamentos,
inscripcion_proyectos.idprofesor,
inscripcion_proyectos.idusuarios,
inscripcion_alumnos.idinscripcion_proyectos,
inscripcion_alumnos.cedula AS cedulaA,
inscripcion_alumnos.nombres AS nombresA,
inscripcion_alumnos.apellidos AS apellidosA,
profesores.cedula AS cedulaP,
profesores.nombres AS nombresP,
profesores.apellidos AS apellidosP,
usuarios.cedula,
usuarios.nombres,
usuarios.apellidos
FROM inscripcion_proyectos INNER JOIN inscripcion_alumnos AS inscripcion_alumnos ON 
inscripcion_proyectos.id=inscripcion_alumnos.idinscripcion_proyectos 

INNER JOIN profesores AS profesores ON inscripcion_proyectos.idprofesor=profesores.cedula

INNER JOIN usuarios ON inscripcion_proyectos.idusuarios=usuarios.cedula

WHERE inscripcion_proyectos.id='$id' GROUP BY idcodificacion_proyectos";
```

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste hacer la consulta en Navicat o en el propio PhpMyAdmin (La verdad no se que utilices)? ¿Podrías proporcionarnos el SQL?

Comment: ok como hago para subir el sql de la bd jejejej soy nuevo en este foro

Comment: Solo necesitarías exportarlo https://ticket.cdmon.com/es/support/solutions/articles/7000006414-c%C3%B3mo-importar-y-exportar-bases-de-datos-desde-phpmyadmin y después el archivo que te genere, copiar y pegarlo a tu pregunta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hice un query de ejemplo basándome en tu query y efectivamente como dice @ecarrizo el grup by es lo que te esta haciendo que solo visualices un registro.

Anexo el query de ejemplo que hice por si te sirve de algo:

```
declare @inscripcion_proyectos as table(
    id int,
    idcodificacion_proyectos int,
    titulo_proyecto nvarchar(max),
    iddepartamentos int,
    idprofesor int,
    idusuarios int
); 
insert into @inscripcion_proyectos values (1,1,'Proyecto 1', 1,6111,7111)
insert into @inscripcion_proyectos values (2,1,'Proyecto 2', 1,6333,7222)
insert into @inscripcion_proyectos values (3,1,'Proyecto 3', 1,6222,7111)
insert into @inscripcion_proyectos values (4,1,'Proyecto 4', 1,6111,7333)
insert into @inscripcion_proyectos values (5,1,'Proyecto 5', 1,6222,7222)
insert into @inscripcion_proyectos values (6,1,'Proyecto 6', 1,6111,7111)
insert into @inscripcion_proyectos values (7,1,'Proyecto 7', 1,6111,7333)
insert into @inscripcion_proyectos values (8,1,'Proyecto 8', 1,6333,7111)


declare @inscripcion_alumnos as table(
    idinscripcion_proyectos int,
    cedula int,
    nombres nvarchar(max),
    apellidos nvarchar(max)
); 
insert into @inscripcion_alumnos values (1,5111,'Alumno 1', 'Alumno apellido 1')
insert into @inscripcion_alumnos values (2,5112,'Alumno 2', 'Alumno apellido 2')
insert into @inscripcion_alumnos values (3,5113,'Alumno 3', 'Alumno apellido 3')
insert into @inscripcion_alumnos values (1,5114,'Alumno 4', 'Alumno apellido 4')
insert into @inscripcion_alumnos values (1,5115,'Alumno 5', 'Alumno apellido 5')

declare @profesores as table(
    cedula int,
    nombres nvarchar(max),
    apellidos nvarchar(max)
); 
insert into @profesores values (6111,'Profesores 1', 'Profesores apellido 1')
insert into @profesores values (6222,'Profesores 2', 'Profesores apellido 2')
insert into @profesores values (6333,'Profesores 3', 'Profesores apellido 3')

declare @usuarios as table(
    cedula int,
    nombres nvarchar(max),
    apellidos nvarchar(max)
); 
insert into @usuarios values (7111,'Usuario 1', 'Usuario apellido 1')
insert into @usuarios values (7222,'Usuario 2', 'Usuario apellido 2')
insert into @usuarios values (7333,'Usuario 3', 'Usuario apellido 3')

SELECT 
    ip.id, 
    ip.idcodificacion_proyectos,
    ip.titulo_proyecto,
    ip.iddepartamentos,
    ip.idprofesor,
    ip.idusuarios,
    ia.idinscripcion_proyectos,
    ia.cedula AS cedulaA,
    ia.nombres AS nombresA,
    ia.apellidos AS apellidosA,
    p.cedula AS cedulaP,
    p.nombres AS nombresP,
    p.apellidos AS apellidosP,
    u.cedula,
    u.nombres,
    u.apellidos
FROM 
    @inscripcion_proyectos as ip
    inner JOIN @inscripcion_alumnos AS ia
        ON ip.id=ia.idinscripcion_proyectos 
    inner JOIN @profesores AS p 
        ON ip.idprofesor=p.cedula
    inner JOIN @usuarios as u
        ON ip.idusuarios=u.cedula
WHERE ip.id= 1
--GROUP BY idcodificacion_proyectos
```

NOTA: Toma en cuenta lo de los left join, con los inners obligas a que existan los datos en ambas tablas, si no existen en alguna pues no te mostrará la información, con el left join si muestra información pero con valores null para las tablas donde no se encontró la relación.

Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El problema de tu consulta esta en la agrupacion GROUP BY, solo te trae una entrada para el proyecto "X" porque todas las entradas tienen el mismo valor en idcodificacion_proyectos.

Ten en cuenta que si alguno de los INNER JOIN Falla, ese row no se mostrara (ej, si no tienes profesores asignados, pero si alumnos y viceversa), en el caso de que alguno de ambos sea opcional deberias usar LEFT JOIN.

Ademas, Como consejo, nunca deberías confiar en los datos enviados desde el usuario (en este caso id) y escaparlos para evitar SQL Injection.

La manera mas facil de hacerlo es utilizando PDO, http://php.net/manual/es/intro.pdo.php

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda y consejo amigo este es my ultimo proyecto ya estoy migrando a pdo